# Raspberry pi4 with G2TSP

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen

Im  trying to connect an G2TSP touch screen, the display worksfine but the touch doesn't work, just when i unplug and plug the power and the USB(touch).
It doesn't work at power up, but when i connect the cables again the screen works fine, but if i turn off the Pi, and then turn it on the touch of the screen doesn't work

Comment: I mean that i have to disconnect the type-c power cable, and the type-c cable coming from the raspberry, only by doing that the touch works

Comment: It doesn't work at power up, but when i connect the cables again the screen works fine, but if i turn off the Pi, and then turn it on the touch of the screen doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any solution?

Comment: no, I do not have a solution at this time ... your post now has a fairly clear description of the problem, so more people will actually read it ... it looks like the startup scripts are out of sequence ... the touch screen daemon may be starting too early